# Using a class to define tables, how to change rows values?

Tags: c#, dataset

This is on the class, it's working properly

```
public sealed class DataAccess
{
    static readonly DataAccess instance = new DataAccess();

    public DataSet TabelasSET { get; private set; }
    //**add datatables here
    public DataTable tabelaEC0 { get; private set; }

    // Explicit static constructor to tell C# compiler
    // not to mark type as beforefieldinit
    static DataAccess()
    {
    }

    DataAccess()
    {
        this.TabelasSET = new DataSet("TabelasSET");
        //**add datatables here too
        this.tabelaEC0 = new DataTable("tabelaEC0");

        TabelasSET.Tables.Add("tabelaEC0");

        //**add columns
        tabelaEC0.Columns.Add("nome");
        tabelaEC0.Columns.Add("valor");
    }

    public static DataAccess Instance
    {
        get
        {
            return instance;
        }
    }
}
```

This works well with adding rows, on any form, for example:

```
    DataRow row1 = DataAccess.Instance.tabelaEC0.NewRow();
    row1["nome"] = "G";
    row1["valor"] = readG.Text;
    DataAccess.Instance.tabelaEC0.Rows.Add(row1);
```

It's been working perfectly, but sometimes i wanna change the rows value, instead of adding them, that's what i can't do.

UPDATE!
i've tinkered around it and found the following, its possible to import data into a row using the code:

```
DataAccess.Instance.tabelaEC0.LoadDataRow(row1["nomes"], "G");
```

I have however to define row1 out of the method, otherwise he will state that it doesnt exist in the current context

So what i did was defining it as:

```
private object row1;
```

right after the class Form1, the problem now is that he states he can't apply indexing [] to an expression of type object

(The rows are now created after initializing the program, i'm only trying to update their values)

Answer (score 0):

There's a not so clean solution to this, whenever someone wants to update that table, simply do this

```
        DataAccess.Instance.tabelaEC0.Rows.Clear();
```

wich will clean all the table
and then rewrite the table rows

```
        DataRow row1 = DataAccess.Instance.tabelaEC0.NewRow();
        row1["nome"] = "G";
        row1["valor"] = readG.Text;
        DataAccess.Instance.tabelaEC0.Rows.Add(row1);
```

I'm sure there's a cleaner way to update this, but for now this will do, this thread is open to other answers i hope.
(Research sources: Tinkered around c#)